# Why creating a wrong pretty url in Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2, friendly-url

I have the rule:

```
[
    'pattern' => 'category/<name>',
    'route' => 'catalog/main'
],
```

I am getting the current URL on page /category/books:

```
yii\helpers\Url::current();
```

Result: /category/books?%2Fcategory%2Fbooks=

Why?

Answer (score 0):

you can write rules like this

```
'rules' => ['/' => 'site/index',
            'category/<slug:>' => 'category/books']
```

`<slug:>` means you can pass any string to after category